# How and when Kafka Consumer commits offsets in Kafka with EIP frameworks like Apache Camel?How can we handle retry asynchronously with camel-kakfa?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

Sample code of the routing builder as below:

```
    // For out of seq event state (reque)
    onException(OutOfSeqStateException.class)
    .logStackTrace(false).logExhaustedMessageHistory(false)
        .setHeader("eventSource", constant(EventConstants.BACKEND))
        .delay(30000)/*.method(DelayerBean.class , "computeDelayInMillis")*/.asyncDelayed().// delay should be asynchronously
        .setBody().header(EventConstants.BE_STATE_EVENT)// send original event
        .to("direct:requeue");// toendpoint: requeroute

    // For handling other exceptions
    onException(Exception.class)
    .log("EXCEPTION OCCURED.....   ->  \"${exception.message}\"")
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
        .bean(KafkaErrorHandlerBean.class, "handle")
        .handled(true);

    // Backend Events Route
    from(commonCamelConfig.getKafkaConsumerEndpoint())
     .routeId("BackendStateIncomingRoute")
            .id(routeId)
            .to("log:" + fqClassName + "?showAll=true&level=" + logLevel)
            .unmarshal(jdf)
            .bean(MandatoryFieldCheckerBean.class, "performNullCheck")
            // all context info must be present,if not, throw exception
            .bean(ValidateEventHandlerBean.class, "validateIncomingEvents")
            .choice()
            .when().simple("${in.header.isValidEvent} == true",Boolean.class)//enter if valid event(backendstate/backenddata)
                    .choice()
                        .when(header("BEStateEvent").isNotNull())
                            .bean(EventTransformer.class, "getBackendTransformedEvent")
                            .bean(PaymentsService.class, "processMessage")
                            .bean(TransitionalStateHandlerBean.class,"handle")
                            .bean(AMQPProducer.class, "sendEventToMQ")
                            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
                        .otherwise()
                            .bean(EventTransformer.class, "getBackendTransformedEvent")
                            .bean(PaymentsService.class, "processMessage")
                    .endChoice()
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)//acknowledge only valid events, doesnt expect a reply
            .endChoice()
            .end();

    //Reque the original event in case of Retryable Exceptions
    from("direct:requeue").routeId("BackendDirectRequeRoute")
    .bean(RequestRetryHandlerBean.class, "doRetry")
    .to(commonCamelConfig.getKafkaConsumerEndpoint())
    .end();
```

Kafka configuration for the consumer endpoint is as below:

```
    public String getKafkaConsumerEndpoint() {
    return properties.getJmsKafkaBroker()
            + ":" + properties.getKafkaPaymentsOtpTopic()
            + "?brokers="+ properties.getBootstrapServers()
            + "&groupId="+ properties.getGroupId()
            + "&autoOffsetReset="+ properties.getAutoOffsetReset()
            + "&autoCommitEnable=true"
            + "&keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
            + "&valueDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer";
}
```

There are two queries that i have with respect to the above code:

1. At what point of the entire routing, is the kafka consumer commits the offsets or is it an independent task because i have not modified the default value for the field **autoCommitIntervalMs** which is 5 seconds so does it mean it will commit independently after every 5 sec.
2. I want to handle reque scenario in case of an outofsequence exception and the way i am doing this is by creating another endpoint with a delay pattern logic which will send the faulty message to DLQ after max reque time. What are some loopholes in the above logic and is there any better way to handle the same? If this logic seems good then please see that i have used **asyncdelayed()**  for asynchronous delay but it doesnt seem to work and blocks the new messages until requed. Kindly help me to implement asynchronous delay as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using camel version < 2.22 then you can not control offset commit, it happens  in another thread which has default value of 5 seconds which can be changed. If you are using camel version >= 2.22 then only you can control manual-commit of the messages. To use manual commit, set following properties:

autoCommitEnable=false: turn off auto-committing of offsets so we can use manual commits.
allowManualCommit=true: turn on manual commits, gives us access to the KafkaManualCommit capability.
Below is the code snippet:

```
KafkaManualCommit manual =
                        exchange.getIn().getHeader(KafkaConstants.MANUAL_COMMIT, KafkaManualCommit.class);
                if (manual != null) {
                    LOGGER.info("committing the offset manually");
manual.commitSync();
            }
```

2) In your second question, it seems that you want to put the message again back on kafka to process. But from your code it seems you are using same endpoint for consumer and producer. When you want to produce the message in kafka, you need to specify "topic", "partition" and "key" of the message which I do not see in your code. Talking about the loop holes, because you are putting the messages in kafka again, what if the message was corrupt, so you will keep on getting the same exception and putting the same message again n again back in kafka. I would suggest to retry the message in the same route. Below is the code snippet:

```
onException(YourException.class)
                .maximumRedeliveries(3) // You can call some method too
                .redeliveryDelay(100) // You can call some method too
                .onRedelivery(exchange -> {
                    int retryCount = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.REDELIVERY_COUNTER, Integer.class);
                    log.debug("Recoverable exception occurred. Retried {} time " , retryCount);
                })
                .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.DEBUG)
                .to("someOtherRoute // Probably to error-topic
```